# use wp_send_json() | wp_die() | die() in external function

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I try to accomplish the following structure

```
add_action('wp_ajax_theaction','theaction');
function theaction () {
    $input = $_POST['input'];
    do_action('thehook',$input);
}
```

Other php file

```
add_action('thehook','doit');
function doit ($input) {
    $output = array('hello',$input);
    wp_send_json($output);
}
```

My code works great if I don't go via a custom hook, but as shown above, the ajax call returns an empty string.

Comment: What's your question? Please add your shortcode code, so we can know what's going on there.

Comment: @ucheng Oh I'm sorry, I mixed up "do_shortcode" with "do_action". Checking the updated post, are you able follow?

Comment: I run the code without any problem.